# How can I rewrite a text scramble pure js code in vueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, nuxt.js, scramble

I need to readapt a pure JavaScript code into a vue.js template. 
The base for it is this Text Scramble Effect: https://codepen.io/soulwire/pen/mErPAK 
Here is my version: 
https://codepen.io/iuliard/pen/ExyYyow

Unfortunately I have to redo this in vue.js/nuxt since I am adding a back-end to my website.
Is there a way to achieve the same result? Or is there a way of encapsulating the pure js and somehow make it work inside a template like this:

```
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="hfkfaq">
      <!-- TODO: HFK FAQ text scramble script -->
      <div class="text">
        <span class="dud">HFK</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script></script>

<style lang="postcss"></style>
```

Any help is much appreciated! Pure CSS animation tips can also help.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to SO. It would be perfect if you're able to recreate in a codepen what YOU've tried, it'd be easier for us to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. Here is it: https://codepen.io/iuliard/pen/ExyYyow